# getting warning 'Failed To Open Stream' in including a file

Tags: php

i m using following code

`include 'popularCities.php?country=';`

but i am getting below warning plz help me

`Warning: Include(PopularCities.Php?Country=): Failed To Open Stream: No Error In C:\Xampp\Htdocs\AssetFinder\Includes\Header.Php On Line 59`

`Warning: Include(): Failed Opening 'PopularCities.Php?Country=' For Inclusion (Include_path='.;C:\Xampp\Php\PEAR') In C:\Xampp\Htdocs\AssetFinder\Includes\Header.Php On Line 59`

Comment: check the including file's path

Answer (score 1):

`include 'popularCities.php?country=';`

problem is with query string remove `'?country=`' from file name because `include()` only includes a file content so filename must be popularCities.php

use following,
`include ("popularCities.php");`

for that countries, you can set session for `country_id` or use ajax request to setup country--state--city respectively.